# How to abort a deploy if a command within a hook script fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Under Amazon Linux 2 based Elastic Beanstalk Environments, you can have [code that runs on deployment or configuration changes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) by including scripts in the `.platform/hooks` and `.platform/confighooks` directories.

However, if one of the commands in my hooks script fails, the deploy is not aborted.  This can cause problems because it means that the deploy may succeed without actually having working code.

For example, if I have the following hooks script and the npm install fails, my deploy will still go through but without all of the npm packages:

```
#!/bin/bash

npm install --production

other_command
other_command_2
```

How do I cause a failed command in this script to bubble up to aborting the deploy?

Answer (score 2):

Use `set -e` at the start of your script.

Elastic Beanstalk will abort the deploy if the hook itself fails.  In this case, "failure" is measured by the return code of the process.  The issue is that the default return code of a bash script is the return code of the final command in the script.  (For a minimalist example, the bash script `false` returns 1, where the bash script `false; true` returns 0).  Thus, the successful commands after the failed one are fooling Elastic Beanstalk into believing the hook has succeeded.

Adding [`set -e`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) at the start of your script will cause bash to stop running the script if any of the commands fail and return the error code of the failed command.  This will in turn tell Elastic Beanstalk that the hook failed and Elastic Beanstalk will abort the command.

The full script would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

npm install --production

other_command
other_command_2
```